# Return a column entry from Insert row query - MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Heres the scenario:
I am supposed to make a small site where user can register, I am using a table named users with fields

```
userid int unsigned auto_increment,
name varchar(50),
gender enum('m','f'),
time datetime,
joiningyear int unsigned,
primary key (userid)
```

When I insert a new user I am also supposed to log him in by saving an encrypted form of his userid as a cookie. The problem is this, if userid is already used, it is auto incremented by 1, as is obvious. I would like to recieve this new value as an **output** of my insert query, without adding another query that fetches it, this will makes things easy.

Currently I am using two seperate queries one checking if randomly chosen userid is already taken and second inserting the entry.
`Insert into users(......) values(...)`

Is there a way to achieve this with one query?

Comment: After you insert it, it becomes available in the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function, to use in your next query in MySQL, or via `mysql_insert_id()` in PHP (or whatever your API provides).  You generally _do not_ need to query for the id unless you perform intervening inserts.

Comment: your storing the cookie value in table..?

Comment: Why not save a joining date instead of a year..

Comment: the user id is auto_increment, how can it will be already used..?

Comment: PHP/MySQL regulars, do we have a reference question for this? I can never find it if we do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your MySql adapter you can use:

[`mysqli_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) or [`PDO::lastInsertId`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php). There is also [`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) but described with:

> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information.

If you are using any framework, it should support returning last inserted id.

Comment: `mysqli` and PDO are the only ones worth considering here. `mysql` is too dangerous to use.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_insert_id() will give you the last inserted ID for a new user.  As long as you do not have a massive influx you should be fine to use this.

Ultimately, a second query to retrieve the information based on their input information would be fine then store that to the cookie.

Comment: Even with a massive influx, it is fine. The values is connection-dependent, and each script gets its own connection. Unless multiple inserts are performed which cause the value to be overwritten, it will be available in the same PHP script no matter how many other concurrent users there are.